how to do vnet to vnet two way peering
i have an existing vnet module in bicep. and i want to create two vnets, namely vnet1 and vnet2. i want these two vnets to have two way peering with my existing vnet. please i need steps on how to get this done in code
I created modules for vnet1 and vnet2 and then tried doing a peering connection between vnet1 to vnet and the reverse and also doing a peering of vnet2 to vnet and its reverse. I am using bicep modules to try to accomplish. I need the required parameters of each vnets module and how they are declared and how to make sure it deploys successfully using github actions workflow. These are values to use for the vnet1 and vnet2 peerings(these are dummy values):
Peer to vNet1:
vNet: ooo-mgmt-dev-vn-01
RG: ooo-mgmt-rg-networking-01
Sub: ooo-mgmt-dev-02
Peer to vNet2:
vNet: ooo-mgmt-dev-vn-01-02
RG: ooo-mgmt-rg-networking-01
Sub: ooo-mgmt-dev-02
There must be an existing vnet for these two vnets to do 2 way peerings with. Feel necessary to include any bicep files or bicepparam files. Thank you
